# How do I make multiple tabs open in a new window?

Tags: javascript, html

I use this script to create a button which opens the 3 links in new tabs, but in the same window

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win() 
{    
    window.open("https://google.com/")
    window.open("https://www.gmail.com/")
    window.open("https://www.facebook.com/")
}   
</script></head>
<body>   
<form> <input type=button value="Start a Blog" onclick="open_win()"> </form>
</body> </html>
```

I found another code to open a link in new window of 300*250.

```
<a href="https://google.com/" onclick= "window.open('https://google.com/','newwindow','width=300,height=250'); 
return false;">  </a>
```

Now , I want to combine these two. I want a button as in the first case, to open a new window of 300*250 and then open the three links in new tabs in that window.

Comment: `window.open` second parameter should be `_blank`, as from the docs: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: @CapitanFindus The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is often significantly better than anything w3schools has to offer.

Comment: Opening windows with fixed sizes is *really* annoying and is a good way to get people to hate your application, especially if they're using a mobile browser.

Comment: @tadman yes it is, but it was just a wrong parameter issue

Comment: @CapitanFindus stop reading w3schools unless you are actively seeking to be misinformed. The 2nd parameter of window.open corresponds to the window name. _blank is a special window name that will *always* give you a new window. Why would it be a parameter with only one legal value??

Comment: At a guess, you might be able to do this by opening a single page in a new window, then spawning additional tabs directly from this new window rather than the originating window. Sounds like it might seem very similar to malicious popups though, and I suspect the browser will interfere.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `window.open` can create two different kinds of windows, depending on whether certain options are specified in the third argument:

- Normal browsing windows (which most modern browsers will open in tabs of the current window)
- Popup windows (which cannot contain tabs)

There is no way to "mix and match" these two options.